# packing grid into frame on python with tinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have this loop:

```
 for y in range(0,matrixsize):
    button = Button(win, text=" ", height = 5, width = 10, **kwargs2)
    button.grid(row=x, column=y)
    button.pack()
```

I am trying to pack the grid so that that it can be fit in a frame, unfortunately i cannot figure out how to do this so that it still continues to have both columns and rows. I tried doing button.pack(fill=both) but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

"pack the grid that that it can be fit in a frame" makes absolutely no sense. A "grid" isn't an object. `grid` is merely a function call. It can't be "packed".

You can't use both `pack` and `grid` on the same widget. It's one or the other. When you call `pack()`, any effects by previously calling `grid()` will be lost.

It's unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish, but whatever it is, it can probably be done by applying appropriate options to `grid`, along with configuring weights to rows and columns. Or, you can use `grid` to arrange your buttons in a frame, and the use `pack` to put that frame in some other frame.